# Gnome Extension & Linux Versioning Confusion

Tags: shell, gnome, version

I'm really very new to Linux DE. I'm still getting my feet wet and to be honest I'm finding some elements amazing and some elements just plain baffling.

I've been looking at guides on setup and configuration. I'm running the latest Pop!_OS (20.10). I was just reading a guide and I've seen GNOME Extensions mentioned a number of times so decided to check it out.

Confusion ensues.

I went to the download [here](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/307/dash-to-dock/) and selected the drop down for the shell version. The newest in the list is 3.38. OK, I thought to myself, how do I know my version. Looked it up ...

```
$SHELL --version
GNU bash, version 5.0.17(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

Oh ... I'm two major versions ahead! I thought to myself "But people are still using it ... ?"

Then I read some of the comments, the second comment then points to a download for GNOME 40!! 35 major version ahead of me!!?!

At this point I'm so confused over versioning that these version numbers are starting to feel meaningless. I'm a software engineer myself so version numbers are something I understand, but this? I'm truly and utterly baffled by things like this.

I'm sure this all makes perfect sense to you guys but can anyone help a noob out of this forest of version numbering confusion?

What is going on here? Are these numbers even really referencing the same things? How can someone be running GNOME 40 when I just downloaded the latest Pop!_OS just yesterday with GNOME 5?

Yours,

Sir Baffled of Lower-Confusedville

Comment: That web site allows you to download a dock for the **Gnome shell**. You checked the version of **Bash**. Not the same thing at all. Unfortunately the term "shell" can mean many different things. For more confusion, [Gnome 40](https://forty.gnome.org/) seems to be the successor of Gnome 3. You need to find out which version of Gnome is installed (I suggest you ask the internet; I don't know how to do that) and download the corresponding version of *Dash to Dock*.

Comment: Check Gnome version: https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/gnome-version.html.en